# deploying webservice

Tags: web-services

I need to deploy webservice on server which contain OS as a 'OS2200'..Is there any tool for deploying webservice.If it is windows OS i can use IIS for publishing Webservice here that is not the case it is a different OS

Comment: ServerFault? If you can explain what OS2200 is, of course :)
Do you mean Mainframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, any computer that runs TCP/IP can run a webservice, but your question should probably be rephrased to something like "I use COBOL for OS2200, how do I implement a webservice in that programming language?" As far as I see, COBOL, Fortrans, C and assembler are popular programming languages on OS2200.